# DDD: should "Comment" in an "Article" be an aggregate root?

Tags: domain-driven-design, aggregateroot

I am starting to design a first simple application DDD-style, and I am starting to see how the concepts work together.

If I design a classic blog application, Article class will be one of my aggregate roots. I want to retrieve articles, manage and delete all the related data (publication date, authors...). I am having difficulties with comments. At first, Comment seems to be an entity that is part of the Article aggregate: a comment is created in relation to an article, if I delete an Article, I will delete related comments.

Then I want to display a small box on the blog with the latest comments posted on the blog, for any article. So it looks like I want to retrieve comments from my data store (and only comments). From my understanding of DDD ideas, that makes it an aggregate root. But that does not seem totally right as Comment seems to depend strongly on Article.

How would you model it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

When you think about it you will probably find various reasons why a `Comment` should be an *Aggregate* itself:

- You want to list the latest comments
- You may want to list all comments by a particular user
- You may want comments to be nested (a comment being a reply to another comment)
- You may want to approve/reject comments through an admin interface
- A user may want to edit or delete his/her comment
- ...

I take the following as a general rule of thumb: Keep your Aggregates as small as possible. When in doubt, err on the side of more Aggregates.

By modelling it this way, you can attach the comments to multiple objects, like `Article` and `User`

```
Comment
    string Text
    string UserName
    bool IsApproved

Article
    string Title
    string Body
    ...
    List<CommentIds> CommentIds

User
    string UserName
    ...
    List<CommentIds> CommentIds

ListOfTenLatestComments
    List<CommentIds> CommentIds
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your advice, I does answser my question.

Comment: You create an aggregate for the ten latest comment? Isn't it more a view of the comments?

Comment: @AntoineRoux can be either. Depends on the context. I usually use domain events to populate views for this purpose, but mentioning this in my answer would have let away from the original question.

Comment: When I add a new Comment to Article, two aggregate change in same transaction, add new Comment and attach to article. Is this an issue?

Comment: @oguzh4n Looking at my model after more than a year has passed, I might model it the other way around. A comment refers to the article and the commenting user through `ArticleId` and `UserId`. Neither Article nor User need a list of comment ids. Creating a new comment would be one transaction affecting one aggregate: The creation of the new comment with the respective ids. Listing comments by user or by article would be a mere projection (perhaps a JOIN in a SQL database or a read model in an event sources scenario).

Comment: @DennisTraub "Neither Article nor User need a list of comment ids" ok but you say "By modelling it this way, you can attach the comments to multiple objects, like Article and User" how can I attach if don't have list in Article or User aggregates? Comment haven't ArticleId and UserId

Comment: @oguzh4n As I wrote in my previous comment, I'd modify the `Comment` class so that it refers to its `Article` and its `User` through an `ArticleId` and `UserId` respectively.

Comment: I'm, donwvoting, since as you already noticed, coupling user with list of comment ids is a bad idea. Please add an UPDATE to you answer, so it won't missguide others.